# Setup spring-boot project with mysql database using mysql driver

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

MySQL connector is a part of maven dependencies and all the database properties like url,username,password are mentioned in the application.properties.

Getting a RuntimeException, like:

> Driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl,
>   jdbc/mysql://10.53.235.141:3306/hms.

Please help with the solution.

```
application.properties

 spring.datasource.url=jdbc/mysql://10.53.235.141:3306/hms
 spring.datasource.username="root"
 spring.datasource.password="password"
 spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 spring.jpa.database = MYSQL

[![Project setup structure][1]][1]
```

[image: Exception in the console]

Comment: `jdbc:mysql://10.53.235.141:3306/hms"` use this

Answer (score 6):

Format of URL is wrong, use below URL

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://10.53.235.141:3306/hms`

instead of

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc/mysql://10.53.235.141:3306/hms
```

Answer (score 1):

Your url is wrong use this

```
jdbc:mysql://10.53.235.141:3306/hms"
```